# Visual Studio + Team foundation? 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I am thinking about upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010. I came accross this:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Foundation-Upgrade/dp/B0038KTORY/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1291799898&sr=8-6

Can I use this to upgrade whilst also getting Team foundation server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package is just Team Foundation Server and not Visual Studio of any edition included.

Just spoken to a MS Rep and was told you can use that if you have purchased a previous version of Visual Studio, you qualify. If for example you have VS Pro 2005, you can purchase upgrade professional edition in addition to upgrade TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says "All editions of Visual Studio 2008 can be upgraded to Visual Studio 2010". I have VS 2008 prof. so the question remains - do I still have to purchase the VS 2010 upgrade or is it included in this as well?

Comment: As I said, no - That does not include Visual Studio, that package is just Team Foundation Server.